# Trying to understand implementation of gaussian blurring in matlab

Tags: image-processing, distribution, matlab, gaussian

I am trying to blur a scanned text document to the point that the text lines are blurred to black.. I mean the text blends into each other and all I see are black lines.

I'm new to MATLAB and even though I know the basics I cannot get the image to blur properly. I have read this: [Gaussian Blurr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) and according to that the blur is managed/decided by the sigma function. But that is not how it works in the code I wrote.

While trying to learn Gaussian blurring in Matlab I came to find out that its achieved by using this function: `fspecial('gaussian',hsize,sigma);`

So apparently there are two variables `hsize` specifies number of rows or columns in the function while `sigma` is the standard deviation.

Can some one please explain the significance of `hsize` here and why it has a much deeper effect on the result even more than `sigma`?

Why is it that even if I increase `sigma` to a very high value the blurr is not effected but the image is distorted a lot by increasing the `hsize`

here is my code:

```
img = imread('c:\new.jpg');

h = fspecial('gaussian',hsize,sigma);

out = imfilter(img,h);

imshow(out);
```

and the results are attached:

Why is it not only controlled by `sigma`? What role does `hsize` play? Why cant I get it to blur the text only rather than distort the entire image?

Thank you

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Examples that don't take up so much space would be sufficient and would be appreciated. You could just crop these images and re-upload.

Comment: Also, please specify, which values of `hsize` and `sigma` you used to generate them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hsize` refers to the size of the filter. Specifically, a filter that is Nx
x Ny pixels uses a pixel region Nx x Ny in size centered around each
pixel when computing the response of the filter. The response is just how 
the pixels in that region are combined together. In the case of a
gaussian filter, the intensity at each pixel around the central one is
weighted according to a gaussian function prior to performing a box average over the region.
`sigma` refers to the standard deviation of the gaussian (see [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/images/ref/fspecial.html)
for `fspecial`) with units in pixels. As you increase `sigma` (keeping the
size of the filter the same) eventually you approach a simple box average with uniform weighting
over the filter area around the central pixel, so you stop seeing an effect from increasing `sigma`.

The similarity between results obtained with gaussian blur (with large value of sigma) and a box
average are shown in the left and middle images below. The right image shows
the results of eroding the image, which is probably what you want.

[image]

The code:

```
% gaussian filter:
hsize = 5;
sigma = 10;
h = fspecial('gaussian',hsize,sigma);
out = imfilter(img,h);

% box filter:
h = fspecial('average',hsize);
out = imfilter(img,h);

% erode:
se=strel('ball',4,4); 
out = imerode(img,se);
```

Comment: Thank you. ``imerode`` is excatly what I was looking for. I used ``imerode`` with different ``strel`` such as ``square`` in place of ``ball`` but got the same result. So why did you use ``ball``? Also why is the result of ``average`` and ``gaussian`` the same? What function does ``average`` follow? Thank you

Comment: `average` performs a uniformly weighted box average. This means that the intensity at each pixel in the filtered image is computed as the average of the surrounding pixels in a box of size `hsize`. In the case of `gaussian` the pixels are not weighted uniformly before averaging but rather using a gaussian weighting function centered on the central pixel. I used a ball shape but disk or other probably work as well. Please check the documentation for the available `strel` choices.

Answer (score 1):

Fspecial's Manual

> h = fspecial('gaussian', hsize, sigma) returns a rotationally
>   symmetric Gaussian lowpass filter of size hsize with standard
>   deviation sigma (positive). hsize can be a vector specifying the
>   number of rows and columns in h, or it can be a scalar, in which case
>   h is a square matrix. The default value for hsize is [3 3]; the
>   default value for sigma is 0.5. Not recommended. Use imgaussfilt or
>   imgaussfilt3 instead.

where they say that `fspecial - gaussian` is *not recommended*.
In deciding the standard deviation (sigma), you need still decide *hsize* which affects the blurring. 
In `imgaussfilt`, you decide the standard deviation and the system considers you the rest. 
I can get much more better tolerance levels with `imgaussfilt` and `imgaussfilt3` in my systems in Matlab 2016a, example output [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35970657/54964) in the body

```
im = im2double( imgGray ); 
sigma = 5;
simulatedPsfImage = imgaussfilt(im, sigma); 
simulatedPsfImage = im2double( simulatedPsfImage );
[ measuredResolution, standardError, bestFitData ] = ...
    EstimateResolutionFromPsfImage( simulatedPsfImage, [1.00 1.00] );
```

Note that the tolerance levels of `fspecial` are high `[0.70 1.30]` by default.