# Why this regionprops returns 0x1 struct?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, struct

I am trying to convert the code of MIT's [course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biological-engineering/20-309-biological-engineering-ii-instrumentation-and-measurement-fall-2006/) *Biological Instrumentation and Measurement* in the wiki page [here](http://measurebiology.org/wiki/MATLAB:_Estimating_resolution_from_a_PSF_slide_image) from Matlab 7.3 to Matlab R2016a. 
My input data's features are in the scale of square L2 norm. 
Gaussian kernel should be using the square L2 norm, but I see significant differences between Gaussian functions in Matlab and Octave, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26669589/54964). 
The code is about *Estimating resolution from a PSF slide image* and about the function *EstimateResolutionFromPsfImage* with default values of tolarance `[0.7 1.3]` in Matlab 2016a

```
resolutionEstimate = EstimateResolutionFromPsfImage(im2bw(imgRGB), [0.7 1.3]);
```

where `imgRGB` is

[image]

Output results in complications coming from the fact that the command returns 0x1 struct in `objectProperties` from the line 29 of *EstimateResolutionFromPsfImage*

```
objectProperties = regionprops( dilatedImage, ImageData, ...
    'Area', 'Centroid', 'PixelList', 'PixelValues', 'MaxIntensity' );
```

where I do not understand how it can be zero in the case. 
My workspace is ok at start but after passing the `objecProperties` statement, there is a 0x1 struct which should not be there as almost empty

[image]

and eventually leads to errors

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in EstimateResolutionFromPsfImage (line 108)
    Resolution = mean( allPeakData(:,4) ) ./ 0.336;

Error in masi (line 272)
resolutionEstimate = EstimateResolutionFromPsfImage(im2bw(imgRGB), [0.7 1.3]);
```

Possible reasons

- Input. `ImageData` possible wrong.
- Changes is `regionprops`. I think there are something that I have not understood enough well in `regionprops`. 
  The command `imagesc(dilatedImage)` shows that the matrix `dilatedImage` is null i.e. every cell is null in the matrix, like Shai comments. 
  This confirms that the problem is with `objectProperties` because `dilatedImage` is dependent on the `objectProperties` which is 0x1 struct i.e. causing the complication.
- Conversion from Matlab 7.3 to 2016a. I did not find anything that is only unique for Matlab 7.3 in the code. It should work for Matlab 2016a like for Matlab 7.3.

### Psf image generation based on dhanushka's hint

MIT's code `SimulatePsfSlide` seems to work somehow in generating `psfImg`. 
I am reviewing the effect of different parameters on the result and confirming the result but have some difficulties with overexposed images and and eventually having warnings like

```
Warning: Rank deficient, rank = 4, tol =  1.979466e-12. 
> In nlinfit>LMfit (line 579)
  In nlinfit (line 276)
...
Warning: Rank deficient, rank = 1, tol =  1.979466e-12. 
Warning: Some columns of the Jacobian are effectively zero at the solution,
indicating that the model is insensitive to some of its parameters.  That may be
because those parameters are not present in the model, or otherwise do not
affect the predicted values.  It may also be due to numerical underflow in the
model function, which can sometimes be avoided by choosing better initial
parameter values, or by rescaling or recentering.  Parameter estimates may be
unreliable.
```

Here some line which causes complications where I do not understand why 16 and why conversion with `im2double`

```
simulatedPsfImage = im2double( simulatedPsfImage * 16 );
```

### dhanushka's code in Matlab 2016a

Matlab does not  work with inputs of homogenous changes when the image is not PSF, like the first image.

Dhanushka's filter is not recommended [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html?searchHighlight=fspecial) because of many reasons. 
I get a much better model with significantly greater tolerance (even 1.00) with the code. Replace dhanushka's *not recommended* filter by a better one and use this

```
im = im2double( imgGray ); % zeros( ImageSize ) );
sigma = 5;
simulatedPsfImage = imgaussfilt(im, sigma); 
simulatedPsfImage = im2double( simulatedPsfImage );
[ measuredResolution, standardError, bestFitData ] = ...
    EstimateResolutionFromPsfImage( simulatedPsfImage, [1.00 1.00] );
```

Output is much better

[image]

where `BestFitData = 249.999999999989   249.999999999989    0.00713504020178639 5.31607106546232    -0.000392450463696062`; so estimatedSigma = 5.316, which is worser than dhanushka's second example. 
You will have significant problems with tolerance levels with the `fspecial gaussian` in Matlab, but not in Octave like dhanushka's second example shows.

### Extension to Mars

Mars case with dhanushka's code when input

[image]

Output with `imgaussfilt`

[image]

### Final conclusion

L2 norm is not sufficient here.

---

Why is the output of regionprops here 0x1 struct?

Comment: It means `dilatedImage` is empty - it is all zeros with no objects in it. Try `imagesc(dilatedImage)` and inspect it.

Comment: I don't know why. You'll have to debug `EstimateResolutionFromPsfImage` function to see how `dilatedImage` is computed.

Comment: To my understanding, your input image is not a PSF image. In the link you provided, there's a function (SimulatePsfSlide) to generate a PSF image for testing.

Comment: You are changing the question over and over triying to get a result for your **whole project/exercise** . By this time you should already know that SO is not here to make your project. You can not ask "how to do this whole thing" and go updating it every time someone helps you a bit with anew question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my understanding your input image isn't a PSF image. Quoting from the [link](http://measurebiology.org/wiki/MATLAB:_Estimating_resolution_from_a_PSF_slide_image#Testing_the_code_2) you provided, a PSF image is ***an image of approximate point sources on a dark background***, such as a star field or sub resolution fluorescent microspheres. You can generate such image for testing using the `SimulatePsfSlide` function in the given code.

**EDIT**

I don't have Matlab. I ran the code in Octave with a simple PSF image having a single point source in the middle of the image generated from the code below. You can first try with a simple known image and check the result.

In the code below, you can vary the Gaussian PSF size and sigma and see how nlinfit estimates the sigma.

Over-exposure shouldn't be a problem, those values are clipped according to the test code in the link.

```
 clear all
 close all

 psfSize = 9;
 psfSigma = 5;

 % single point source in the middle: this is the object
 ImageSize = [500 500];
 im = im2double( zeros( ImageSize ) );
 im( int32(ImageSize(1)/2), int32(ImageSize(2)/2) ) = 1;
 % gaussian psf: this is the psf of our imaging system
 h = fspecial('gaussian', [psfSize psfSize], psfSigma);
 % convolve the object with psf: the image, this is what we see
 simulatedPsfImage = imfilter(im, h, 'same');
 simulatedPsfImage = im2double( simulatedPsfImage );
 % estimating resolution
 [ measuredResolution, standardError, bestFitData ] = ...
        EstimateResolutionFromPsfImage( simulatedPsfImage );
```

**Input data and [nlinfit](http://octave.sourceforge.net/optim/function/nlinfit.html) output (beta and MSE only)**: Note that in the second case, the MSE is smaller, indicating that the input data closely matches the model. Also we get the correct sigma.

*psfSize = 9, sigma = 5, estimated sigma = 3.0730*

```
beta = 
2.5000e+002
2.5000e+002
2.0275e-002
3.0730e+000
-4.4688e-004

mse =   1.6114e-006
```

[image: size9]

*psfSize = 25, sigma = 5, estimated sigma = 5.0000*

```
beta = 
2.5000e+002
2.5000e+002
6.5254e-003
5.0000e+000
7.3796e-010

mse =   2.2996e-020
```

[image: size25]

Output in Matlab 2016a with `psfSize=9` and `psfSigma=5`, which shows a significant difference between `fspecial` in Matlab and Octave

[image]

where `bestFitData = 250.000000000593   250.000000000593    0.0202577533025840  3.07726724108174    -0.000451857701021258`; here estimatedSigma = 3.077.

Comment: @Masi What makes you think that the homogeneous image in your first figure is a PSF? (Hint: It isn't which is why it doesn't work)

Comment: @Masi From your edits I get the feeling that you have misunderstood the code I had posted, so I added some clarifications. I'm not suggesting that you should first smooth your input image with a Gaussian filter. I'm just giving a simple example of using the function with a synthetic psf image (without using SimulatePsfSlide). The synthetic image simulations are ideal cases. Also carefully read the comments in EstimateResolutionFromPsfImage. It might need slight modifications for some images. Real images are far from ideal.

Comment: @Masi You can check the difference quantitatively by observing the other output parameters of [nlinfit](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html). The code only uses the estimated model parameters (or beta).

Comment: @Masi I don't think you need Octave, it doesn't seem to provide helpful warning messages as Matlab. For example, I don't get any warnings from nlinfit when I try to fit models to most ill-fitting data. I'll add MSE value for each of the above cases. Other params are quite large vectors/matrices.

Comment: EstimatedSigma is 5.316 with `imgaussfilt` in Matlab but 3.077 with `fspecial`. How did you demand that estimatedSigma stays as 5 in Octave?

Comment: @dhanushka One explanation about differences may be that some input characteristics are not square L2 norm. I think PSF should require square L2 norm. I am using square L2 norm data but the function `EstimateResolutionFromPsfImage` does not accept all my test data without giving in the end error about not PSF data. I think the problem may be caused by limited coverage of the function in square L2 norm.

Comment: Final explanation: L2 norm is not sufficient here in the case here.